# PHP: Fastest way to get huge number of directories including subdirectories into db

Tags: php, database, directory, subdirectory, readdir

How to get all directories including subdirectories separately and save in database in PHP? I am using MySQL and PHP 5.4 and nginx.

Right now I have the following function which uses readdir and does what I want just fine.

```
protected function getSubDirsRecursively($dir)
{
    $result = array();
    $dir = rtrim($dir, '\\/');

    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        $dh = opendir($dir);
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            $currentPath = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;
            if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..' && is_dir($currentPath)) {
                $result[] = $currentPath;
                $result = array_merge($result, $this->getSubDirsRecursively($currentPath));
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

However, the problem is when user has huge number of directories (e.g. 1m) and PHP execution time limit which he cannot change due to shared hosting.

Is it possible to do this with ajax requests and collect directories in portions?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. I do note that your question is somewhat vague. No details on the database you are using? Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: It does not matter what db I use, I believe. The problem here execution timelimit. I have no idea where to stop scanning and how to continue from stopped point in ajax requests, that's why I am expecting some hints from experts

Comment: This is my hint: The obviously easiest option would be to find hosting where the PHP time limit can be set. Anything else will be complicated, as you rightfully assumed.

Comment: The biggest time waster is probably if you do 1m individual database queries, each incurring a roundtrip time. The way to optimise that would be to use one big `INSERT` query. Still, it comes down to: 1) can you traverse your disk fast enough to build the data you want to insert and then 2) execute that large query within the time limit. With the typical timeout of 30 seconds that could be quite tight; only testing it will show. Next try a faster way to parse the directories, perhaps the `ls` shell command is faster. Again: test test test. Last but not least: rethink the entire problem.